# How to draw multiple circle shape in SFML

Tags: sfml

i really want to know how to create a multiple circle shapes in SFML.

I know we can create the circle shape with sf::CircleShape 
I want to create a circle shape with the same radius everytime i click on my screen and i have no idea how to do that, please help me.

Comment: sounds like you havent done any reading on sfml tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an event loop to capture mouse events and any other event for that matter. See https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-events.php for details.
Read the documentation or search via Google for more.